# Incidence Matrix and Graph cycles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be an undirected graph without loops and consider its incidence matrix $N_G$ be a $|V(G)| \times |E(G)|$ matrix such that

$$n_{ij}= \left\{\begin{matrix}
-1 & \text{edge $j$ starts from vertex $i$}\\ 
+1 & \text{edge $j$ ends at vertex $i$}\\ 
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

For an undirected graph $G$ without loops let $G'$ be the directed graph with the same set of vertices and a random direction assigned to each of the original graph's edges.

Show that a set $T\subseteq E(G)$ of edges does not contain a cycle if and only if the respective columns of $N_{G'}$ (the directed graph, since that is the structure on which we defined the incidence matrix in this problem) are linearly independent.

The problem is from a course in Graph Theory in my university. I have a solution, that I will provide below, and I would be grateful if anyone could verify its validity. The other reason why I post this problem is to discuss the proposed solution, that I do not seem to understand.

My attempt:

It suffices to show that $T \subseteq E(G)$ contains a cycle if and only if the respective columns of $N_{G'}$ are linearly dependent.

$(\implies)$ Suppose $T$ contains a cycle (the undirected graph) with edges (WLOG) $e_1,e_2,...,e_k$ and let $n_1,n_2,...,n_k$ be the respective columns in $N_{G'}$. Starting with edge $e_1$, traverse the cycle and set $c_i=1$ when the direction of edge $e_i$ in the directed graph $G'$ matches the direction of traversal and $c_i=-1$ when the directions are opposite. Then it must hold $$\sum c_i n_i =0$$

since the $+1$ in each column vanishes when added to the $-1$ of the next edge leaving the same vertex and the $\pm 1$'s vanish for the first and last vertex of the cycle (since the cycle is a closed path). This shows that $n_i$ are linearly dependent.

$(\impliedby)$ Suppose $n_i$ are linearly dependent. Then there exist $c_i$, not all zero such that $$\sum c_i n_i =0$$

Since at least one of them is nonzero, let's say WLOG $c_1\neq0$, write the sum in the form

$$\sum_{i\geq2} c_in_i = -c_1n_1$$

Now, since we do not know whether $c_i$ are integers, multiply by a constant $A$, such that $Ac_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ (including $c_1$) and set $$\mu_i=Ac_i \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Then we can write the sum as

$$\sum_{i\geq2} \mu_in_i = -\mu_1n_1$$

Now this is the part that I'm not sure about. Since $\mu_i$ are integers, $-\mu_1n_1$ describes something very specific: the traversal of edge $e_1$ in the opposite direction than that in the directed graph $\mu_1$ times. And this is equal to another path: the path $\sum_{i\geq2} \mu_in_i$. So in the undirected graph these two create a cycle.

Is this last part of my solution correct? Is there anything I can do to make the last argument about "what it actually describes?" more rigorous? Also, any other ideas for a solution to the $\impliedby$ part?

In the official solution the first part is exactly the same. However in the $\impliedby$ part the argument that I don't understand at all is as follows:

The induced subgraph $\left \langle e_1,...,e_k \right \rangle$ of $G$ with edges $e_1,...,e_k$ contains no vertex wtih degree $1$ (due to the zero sum) so it cannot be a tree and must thus contain a cycle.

The problem is I do not understand what is defined by the term "degree" in this setting. Is it the indegree? the outdegree? their difference?. Furthermore, I do not understand how the zero sum shows that there cannot be a vertex with degree $1$ (I think these two questions are connected)

Sorry for the long post and the million questions, I've just been working on it since yesterday and I'd love to get a rigorous solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are talking about the degree of a vertex in a subgraph of $G$. Since $G$ is undirected, there is no ambiguity with the word “degree.” Since all vertices have a sum of zero, every vertex included in the subgraph indices by the edges $e_k$ will have at least two edges incident (there will be at least one $+1$ and at least one $-1$), hence no such vertex is degree one.

Comment: You are right, I oversaw the fact that it refers to the undirected graph. For the second part, my problem was that we don't know the values of $c_i$ (they are not necessarily $\pm 1$). What you are saying is that these values don't matter, since they need to cancel out, so each vertex would either have no edges at all, a single edge or edges that would somehow cancel out. Since the interesting case is when the graph is connected so there are no isolated vertices, it must be the case that they cancel out, so they have at least 2 edges and thus a degree $d\geq2$. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: And the case where a vertex has a single edge forces $c_i=0$ for that particular edge. so we are done?